# Lookup #define value dll

Tags: c++

This may turn out to be a really easy question, but made very difficult by me not having used C++ in serious anger for a long time - my skills are rustier than an 80's Fiat!

I have a number of header files that define register addresses as #defines that have been provided to me.

I want to create a .dll that allows me to lookup these values via their name and returns their value as an unsigned long from another dev environment i.e.

```
#define A_REGISTER_ADDRESS 0x40

unsigned long myLookupFunction( string lookup )
{
// return value of #define specified by lookup as unsigned long
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Dave

Comment: `return (unsigned long) A_REGISTER_ADDRESS;` ?

Comment: If that's not it, what is your question?

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Are you expecting a call like 'myLookupFunction("A_REGISTER_ADDRESS")' to return 0x40?

Comment: Not quite as i want to use lookup to identify the #define - assume I can't just do return (long) lookup?

Comment: The string would come from outside the dll - assume I'd pass it as a pointer to a character array.

Comment: @PaulFloyd, how you've defined how an external process would call the function is correct.

Comment: Are you allowed to make changes to the header with these defines or are they provided as-is? Are they changing regularly?

Comment: @ChristianG they are provided as is, and could be likely to change (the values, not the names). I have thought about translating them into a txt readable config file, but some of them refer to other #defines so you'd lose that dynamism.

Comment: Well, no `#define` is "dynamic". They are simply instructions to perform rudimentary text substitution. Once the code is compiled, no `#define` exists anywhere, in any form. So you can't get it back out of the code, unless your macro also converted it into some actual symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a technique like this. This uses a macro generator to produce a std::map from the string name to the value and an enum with the same names and values.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define ADDRESS(apply) \
  apply(PORT1,0x40UL)        \
  apply(PORT2,0x42UL)       \
  apply(PORT3,0x43UL)       

#define CREATE_MAP(name,value) \
  {#name,value},

std::map<std::string, unsigned long> myMap = {ADDRESS(CREATE_MAP)};

#define CREATE_ENUM(name, value) \
  name = value,

enum RegisterAddresses
{
   ADDRESS(CREATE_ENUM)
};


unsigned long myLookupFunction(std::string lookup)
{
    return myMap[lookup];
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "port PORT1 value " << std::hex << myLookupFunction("PORT1") << "\n";
   std::cout << "port PORT2 value " << std::hex << myLookupFunction("PORT2") << "\n";
   std::cout << "port PORT3 value " << std::hex << myLookupFunction("PORT3") << "\n";
   std::cout << "port PORT1 enum value " << std::hex << PORT1 << "\n";
}
```